# How do I tell CreateFile that I want to append to an existing file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, createfile

I am using Delphi 2010 and looking for a way to use CreateFile Windows API function to append data rather than overwriting it in the specified file?

**I am not looking for an optional way to do it such as Append() or Rewrite() or similar.  I am looking specifically to do this by use of CreateFile Windows API function.**

I tried using:

```
// this will open existing file but will **overwrite** data in the file.
fHandle:= CreateFile(PChar(FName), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 
      nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0); 

// this will recreate file each time therefore deleting its original content
fHandle:= CreateFile(PChar(FName), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 
      nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

Much appreciated,

Comment: Why not [`TFileStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Classes.TFileStream)? It is an easy to use wrapper of that API. Or use `CreateFile` and [`THandleStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Classes.THandleStream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify that you want `File_Append_Data` access in the second parameter *without* also requesting `File_Write_Data` access. Then all writes will be at the end of the file.

To open a file, creating it if it doesn't already exist, pass `Open_Always` for the `dwCreationDisposition` parameter. (There are only five possible values documented for that parameter, so it doesn't take long to look down the list and select the one that most closely matches your needs.)

Comment: Hi Rob and thanks for your reply. I am not sure if I am missing somethign, but I already tried using FILE_APPEND_DATA and it is saying that FILE_APPEND_DATA is undeclared. I am using Delphi 2010. Here is what I do: fHandle := CreateFile(PChar(FName), FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, nil, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

Comment: You can declare it yourself. Its value is 4.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that [`OPEN_ALWAYS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) is actually what you need here.

> Opens a file, always.
>   If the specified file exists, the function succeeds and the last-error code is set to **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS** (183).
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero.

And if you are writing then you can remove `GENERIC_READ`.

Another problem that I anticipate is that when the file is opened, the file position is set to the beginning of the file. Seek to the end to deal with that.

```
Win32Check(SetFilePointerEx(fHandle, 0, nil, FILE_END));
```

Alternatively you can use [`FILE_APPEND_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258116.aspx) instead of `GENERIC_WRITE`.

```
Handle:= CreateFile(PChar(Name), FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, 
  nil, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

When you use `FILE_APPEND_DATA`, providing that you do not also use `FILE_WRITE_DATA`, all writes are made to the end of the file, irrespective of the current value of the file pointer.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258116.aspx) says it like this:

> For a file object, the right to append data to the file. (For local files, write operations will not overwrite existing data if this flag is specified without **FILE_WRITE_DATA**.)

Note that older versions of Delphi do not define `FILE_APPEND_DATA` and so you need to:

```
const
  FILE_APPEND_DATA = $0004;
```

---

All this said, I suspect that, a stream or a writer class is a better option here. Are you sure you want to get down and dirty with the Win32 API?

Comment: You can optionally specify `FILE_APPEND_DATA` without `FILE_WRITE_DATA` in the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter of `CreateFile()`, and it will automatically write data to the end of the file without you having to seek to the end of the file manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi REmy and thanks for your reply.  I am not sure if I am missing somethign, but I already tried using FILE_APPEND_DATA and it is saying that FILE_APPEND_DATA is undeclared.  I am using Delphi 2010.  Here is what I do:  fHandle := CreateFile(PChar(FName), FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, nil, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

Comment: @d.b: `FILE_APPEND_DATA` was added to the `Windows` unit in XE.